# Can't reference .netstandard csproj in uwp project using multiple TargetFrameworks

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I am using a .netstandard csproj with TargetFrameworks net45;UAP,Version=v10.0.15063

I also have

- A net45 (classic .NET) class library referencing the .netstandard csproj.
- A UWP class library project referencing the .netstandard csproj.

The classic net45 library can reference classes from the netstandard project without problems.

The UWP project fails during build because it can't find any netstandard project classes.

I already tried  the more basic target framework moniker uap10.0 (as described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks)).

Using TargetFramework netstandard1.4 (single target) in netstandard csproj compiles the UWP project correctly.

Question: Is this a bug or do i get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), UWP 10 supports `netstandard1.4`, so multi-targetting your shared library to include targeting `netstandard1.4` is the best way to support UWP since it will work on any framework supporting that version of .NET Standard.